# Why do C functions using a structure have a pointer in the name

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am looking at the following code (taken from Learn C the Hard Way) and I am confused about the code the function that starts:

```
struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
```

I understand that the "struct Person" is telling C that this function will return that type of structure; I also understand that the function takes a character pointer and 3 integers as arguments. However, what is confusing to me is that the name of the function starts with a "*". I thought that *Person_create is simply the name of the function so I don't understand why it needs the asterisk.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);

    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;

    return who;
}

void Person_destroy(struct Person *who)
{
    assert(who != NULL);

    free(who->name);
    free(who);
}

void Person_print(struct Person *who)
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", who->name);
    printf("\tAge: %d\n", who->age);
    printf("\tHeight: %d\n", who->height);
    printf("\tWeight: %d\n", who->weight);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // make two people structures
    struct Person *joe = Person_create(
            "Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);

    struct Person *frank = Person_create(
            "Frank Blank", 20, 72, 180);

    // print them out and where they are in memory
    printf("Joe is at memory location %p:\n", joe);
    Person_print(joe);

    printf("Frank is at memory location %p:\n", frank);
    Person_print(frank);

    // make everyone age 20 years and print them again
    joe->age += 20;
    joe->height -= 2;
    joe->weight += 40;
    Person_print(joe);

    frank->age += 20;
    frank->weight += 20;
    Person_print(frank);

    // destroy them both so we clean up
    Person_destroy(joe);
    Person_destroy(frank);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The star is part of the return type. `Person_create` returns a pointer to a `Person`

Comment: You ought not use assert to check the return value of malloc.

Comment: @ William Pursell: I will make sure not to do so. The comments are mine but the actual code is a cut and paste.

Comment: "function will return that type of structure" is not correct.  `Person_create()` returns a pointer to "that type of structure".

Answer (score 3):

The space doesn't matter with the *

```
struct Person *Person_create
```

is the same as

```
struct Person* Person_create
```

The function returns a pointer to a struct Person

As an aside comment, I typically keep the * and & with the type, since you are saying the type of "pointer to struct Person".  But others like to put a space between the name and the *.

Comment: I like your (second) method better.

Comment: FYI, people who keep the asterisk "on the right" do that because in variable declarations the asterisk is bound to the variable, not to the type; i.e. `int *a, b` declares `a` as a pointer to `int`, and `b` as a plain `int`.

Comment: ^That's a bad excuse though. That's only ONE case that's justifiable. These people do it for EVERYTHING. The second case always makes more sense in every case except the aforementioned.

Comment: @MatteoItalia is close with that explanation, but not quite on the mark. The real reason for the first style is that the syntax was *designed* so that ["declaration reflects use"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117024/why-was-the-c-syntax-for-arrays-pointers-and-functions-designed-this-way/117039#117039). When there are multiple levels of indirection or abstraction involved, this approach may seem more useful; of course ultimately it comes down to whatever makes you comprehend the code quicker.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the function doesn't return a `struct Person`, it returns a **pointer** to a `struct Person`.

Answer (score 0):

This signature:

```
struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
```

is telling you that the type of the return value is the pointer to the struct Person. The name of the function does not start with the star.

In contrast, the signature of the function that would return `struct Person` looks like this:

```
struct Person Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
```

In general (and very short), in most cases returning the pointer is more economical than returning the whole structure (simply because it takes less space and time to pass a pointer as a return value). This is probably the main reason why the C functions which are supposed to give back the structure usually give back the pointer to it.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I am glad that you mentioned the reason why returning a pointer to the structure is better than returning the structure. However, the next question that comes to mind is that when I create a pointer, I tell C the type by doing type *pointer_name; why isn't it the same with the function, and instead of having "struct Person *", go with "struct *Person". I know I am missing something there.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to look deeper into what happens when values are passed around between functions, there are some notes which might help: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html

Comment: @user245185: Because `struct Person` is the type.  So when you have a `Person` pointer, it's `struct Person *myVariable`.  When you have a function that returns a `Person` pointer, *it's exactly the same*, `struct Person *myFunction()`.

Comment: @Dietric Epp: Got it; I was fully understanding that the entire type is "struct Person". :-)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned the * is a part of the return type. You need to return a pointer and not the struct itself because the struct will only exist in the functions stack memory. Once the function returns you will no longer have access to it and it will be garbage.
Only primitives and pointers should be returned this way.

If you insist on returning a struct it needs to be allocated to the heap using malloc inside the function. Later on this memory can be reclaimed by using free if you reference it first. The problem with this is it becomes taxing to remember which structs are allocated and which are not. When freeing the structs it would be a really easy way to run into hard to track down segmentation faults.

In general you should return pointers and primitives because anything else can be big and costly. Depending on your cpu architecture a pointer is about the same size as an int which is next to nothing.

If you're working with struct* 's remember to use -> instead of . to get to its properties.